# Why range of diagram is something else while it is looking like 0 to 1?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

> Calculate the volume integral of T = xyz2 over the prism in
> Fig. 1.24

> [image]

When I had looked at the picture, I was thinking that range of x is 0 to 1 which is pretty clear from the diagram. Later I noticed they wrote range of x is 0 to 1-y, Why? Is it for the right "curvy plane"?

Comment: When $y = 0.5$ for example, can $x$ be $1$?

Comment: @MathLover guess - Yes!! But according to diagram no!

Comment: No! It *cannot* be $1$.

Comment: The range of $x$ is not independent of $y$. It is not a rectangle or a square base. So for each value of $y$ between $0$ and $1$, the $x$ is between $0$ and $(1-y)$. Only when $y = 0$, the range of $x$ can be $0$ to $1$.